# Helix toolkit Tessellation samples is not rendering model

Tags: sharpdx, helix-3d-toolkit

Able to Build the tessellation sample application provided in the following path: **helix-toolkit/Source/Examples/WPF.SharpDX/TessellationDemo/**

When I run the application , i did not see any model rendering. refer screenshot.
[Screen shot of tessellation sample application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJnfj.jpg)
Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. In my code geometry null or not checking condition is wrong. 
thanks